# SVG Color Change on Hover Effect

Tags: css, svg, hover

svg are somewhat tricky. I have some social icons with svg code and when I tried to color change on hover effect, it didn't want to change the color. My svg code looked like this.

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" width="30px" focusable="false" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path class="social-icon contact-icon" d="M19.9,2H4.1C3,2,2,3,2,4.1v15.7C2,21,3,22,4.1,22h6.1v-6.8H7.5V12h2.8V9.6c0-2.8,1.7-4.3,4.2-4.3c1.2,0,2.5,0.2,2.5,0.2v2.7
    h-1.4c-1.4,0-1.8,0.9-1.8,1.7V12h3.1l-0.5,3.2h-2.6V22h6.1c1.2,0,2.1-1,2.1-2.1V4.1C22,3,21,2,19.9,2z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: How are you displaying the SVG?  If you want to style the SVG, it'll need to be inline in your page.  You can't style it if it is loaded via an `<img>`, `background-image`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

When you have path inside the svg tag just like me, you need to indicate the path to make it change the color.

So the css that solved my issue was:

```
svg:hover .social-icon {
       fill: #color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
svg:hover{fill: red}
```

```html
<svg aria-hidden="true" width="30px" focusable="false" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path class="social-icon contact-icon" d="M19.9,2H4.1C3,2,2,3,2,4.1v15.7C2,21,3,22,4.1,22h6.1v-6.8H7.5V12h2.8V9.6c0-2.8,1.7-4.3,4.2-4.3c1.2,0,2.5,0.2,2.5,0.2v2.7
    h-1.4c-1.4,0-1.8,0.9-1.8,1.7V12h3.1l-0.5,3.2h-2.6V22h6.1c1.2,0,2.1-1,2.1-2.1V4.1C22,3,21,2,19.9,2z" />
</svg>
```